# Keyboard layout indicator missing from the Panel

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, indicator, panel

For that I need to type English, French and Chinese, I'm using fcitx to manage the Chinese input methods and I need to change the keyboard layout very often. I've checked the option "Show the input source in the top menu bar", but it doesn't works.

But I find out that, when I login as a guest, all the input things works perfectly, but when I login as my current user, the keyboard layout icon is not displayed. Just as the image showed below:

[Keyboard indicator disappear from top menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQkmP.png)
[Keyboard indicator displayed in guest mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsrGr.png)

So I guess it might be a user configuration error, did you know where to configure the Panel icons or reinitialize user's configure?

Comment: Can't tell where exactly the problem lies. I would have created a new user account, and moved the files I wanted to keep to the new account.